# Laptop can’t boot. How to tell if the internal hard drive is physically damaged?

Tags: hard-drive, usb

My Asus laptop can't boot. When I tried to repair it using bootable Windows 10 USB's command line, `chkdsk C: /f /r` report not issue.

I then removed the hard drive from the computer and put it into a Sabrent SATA hard drive USB 3.0 enclosure. I don't see the USB at all when I connected the enclosure to a computer (I have tried multiple USB ports with 2 different computers). Plus, I am not sure the hard drive is spinning because there is no obvious noise.

To make sure it isn't physically damaged, I put it back to the original laptop and retried the `chkdsk C: /f /r` (with the help of bootable USB), it still finished the checking of the whole disk without any error.

Can anyone advise how to tell whether this hard drive is physically damaged? I am trying to rescue some data from it.

Comment: check the SMART stats on the disk. I use speedfan/crystaldiskinfo to read SMART stats on windows, and gnome-disks/palimpsest/smartmonctl in linux. SMART info won't identify all possible hardware issues, but in most cases you won't be able to read the smart data if the disk controller circuitry is damaged anyway.

Comment: If you suspect it is damaged, use ddrescue to pull as much data as possible from it. If ddrescue runs without errors and SMART doea not report issues its almost certainly OK. If ddrescue reports errors, well its pulling a bitcopy if as much data as it can off anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to another computer, you can make a bootable CD or USB-stick with a tool, or suite of tools like Ultimate Boot CD:

https://www.ultimatebootcd.com/

This particular suite includes tools like DiskCheck, DISKINFO, TestDisk, etc. which are more capable than chkdsk and which you can use to test your drive and see if it A) is found and responds normally and B) run tests with it and C) in case of just partition or OS gone haywire, sometimes repair it (or atleast wipe it clean and see if all the areas of the disk are still readable and writable).

If none of these tools can find or run tests on your drive (and other drives still work normally in the same computer, so that you know the computer itself isn't at fault), it's a safe bet that it is somehow damaged. After that it's either replacement, or in case of irreplaceable data, a trip to the data recovery company.